# Firebase authWithOAuthPopup to log into Facebook gives warning

Tags: javascript, firebase

Using this in my code:

```
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) { ... });
```

I get the following warning in the bottom of the dialog that appears, for an app that hasn't previously gotten permission to run:

> You are using a display type of 'popup' in a large browser window or
>   tab. For a better user experience, show this dialog with our
>   JavaScript SDK without specifying an explicit display type. The SDK
>   will choose the best display type for each environment. Alternatively,
>   set height and width on your window.open() call to properly size this
>   dialog if you have special requirements precluding you from using the
>   SDK. This message is only visible to developers of your application.

I'm assuming that this is a bug in Firebase.  Am I wrong?

Comment: It's a warning. You should use the FB JS SDK and the `FB.login()` method to provide the best user experience.

Answer (score 11):

[Engineer at Firebase] This is working-as-intended. The Firebase API manually configures the display parameters of the Facebook popup to best match the platform and environment that you're using. This warning is shown to the developers of the application, encouraging you to use the Facebook JavaScript SDK rather than the generic OAuth flow.

**Note:** This warning from Facebook is only shown to the developers listed on the Facebook application, and your end users won't see it.